# New module interacting with other modules

Tags: sugarcrm

I'm trying to create my first custom module in Sugar CRM CE.

I have created a new folder in the "/modules" folder and then placed core files so that the module appears as a new tab in top module menu bar.

At first I want this module to create and search through the contacts data but i have no idea where to write code. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use Module Builder in the product to build the module?